# Looking folder asp netcore in docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, ubuntu

I managed to publish the asp.netcore webApi to the docker container and it worked fine, and I saved the images in the `AppData` folder, but I haven't been able to find a way to see where the `AppData` folder is in the docker container. How do I see the folders that have been published to the Docker container?

[Asp.netcore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olz5M.png)

Comment: Use the command docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash to get a bash shell in the container.